# Dynamic pool size in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, callback, subprocess, multiprocessing, pool

Is there a way to dynamically adjust the `multiprocessing.Pool` size? I'm writing a simple server processes that spawns workers to handle new tasks. Using `multiprocessing.Process` might be better suited (since the number of workers should not be fixed) for this case, but I need to execute a custom callback in my parent process after the spawned child has exited. For some reason, only `mulitprocessing.Pool.apply_async` seems to offer a callback parameter (`multiprocessing.Process` does not).

Comment: Take a look at the answer to question [_multiprocessing - pool allocation_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348156/multiprocessing-pool-allocation).

Answer (score 1):

[Billiard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/billiard) processing Pool allows to [grow](https://github.com/celery/billiard/blob/master/billiard/pool.py#L1255) and [shrink](https://github.com/celery/billiard/blob/master/billiard/pool.py#L1243) the Pool size.

[Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble/3.1.17) allows to run processes assigning a [callback](http://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/#concurrent) once done.

Comment: permalinks for billiard.Pool: [shrink](https://github.com/celery/billiard/blob/ff8efc5d689ef048f5203593390f1ff6a052a5d5/billiard/pool.py#L1285) and [grow](https://github.com/celery/billiard/blob/ff8efc5d689ef048f5203593390f1ff6a052a5d5/billiard/pool.py#L1297)